# Higher homotopy groups of a Zariski closed subset of $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory

Suppose $V\subset \mathbb C^n$ is a Zariski closed subset. Is it true that the higher homotopy groups $\pi_i(\mathbb C^n-V)$ vanish for $0<i<$ some number depending on the codimension of $V$ in $\mathbb C^n$?

Answer (score 6):

I think that $\pi _i(\Bbb{C}^n-V)$ is zero for $i\leq 2c-2$, with $c:=\mathrm{codim}(V)$. Indeed $c\geq 2$ guarantees $\pi _1=0$; then the exact sequence of cohomology
$$ H_c^{2n-i-1}(V)\rightarrow H_c^{2n-i}(\Bbb{C}^n-V)\rightarrow H_c^{2n-i}(\Bbb{C}^n) $$
(any coefficients) + Poincaré duality gives $H_i(\Bbb{C}^n-V)=0$ for $2n-i-1>2\dim (V)$, that is, $i\leq 2c-2$. One concludes with the Hurewicz theorem.

Comment: You should add: And i>0 in the second to last sentence. Do you know a reference for the vanishing of the compact generated cohomology if V is not smooth?

Comment: I want to add that the bound is also clearly optimal: $\mathbb{C}^n - \mathbb{C}^k$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{2n-2k-1}$. So nice theorem!

Comment: @Lennart Meier: A reference is Corollary 3.1.7. in the book of A. Dimca, *Sheaves in Topology*.